# Copy constructor messes up an overloaded output operator

Tags: c++, constructor, runtime, operator-keyword

I have made a program with two classes. On the first one CAuto I've overloaded the << to output the CAuto data.

```
class CAuto
{
private:
    string license_plate,maker,color;
    int year, run;
public:
    CAuto() {}
    CAuto(string get_plate, string get_maker, string get_color, int get_year, int get_run) //ekpliciten construktor
    {
        license_plate = get_plate;
        maker = get_maker;
        color = get_color;
        year = get_year;
        run = get_run;
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const CAuto& obj)
    {
        out << "License: " << obj.license_plate << "\nMaker: " << obj.maker << "\nYear: " << obj.year << "\nColor: " << obj.color << "\nRun: " << obj.run;
        return out;
    }
    void operator =(const CAuto& obj) //operator za prisvoqvane
    {
        license_plate = obj.license_plate;
        maker = obj.maker;
        color = obj.color;
        year = obj.year;
        run = obj.run;
    }
};
```

My second class CAvtopark contains 1 CAuto variable and I wanted to be able to output an entire CAvtopark object. My CAvtopark class has a copy constructor and I noticed that when it is included the CAvtopark output does not work in the sense that it can not get the CAuto data. Why is that?

```
class CAvtopark
{
private:
    CAuto car;
    string name,chain;
    int autopark_count, sales;
public:
    CAvtopark(CAuto get_car, string get_name, string get_chain, int get_autopark_count, int get_sales)
    {
        car = get_car;
        name = get_name;
        chain = get_chain;
        autopark_count = get_autopark_count;
        sales = get_sales;
    }
    CAvtopark(const CAvtopark& obj1)
    {
        name = obj1.name;
        chain = obj1.chain;
        autopark_count = obj1.autopark_count;
        sales = obj1.sales;
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const CAvtopark& obj)
    {
        out << "\nAvtopark name: " << obj.name << "\nAvtopark chain: " << obj.chain << "\nAvtopark count: " << obj.autopark_count << "\nAvtopark sales: " << obj.sales;
        out << endl << obj.car;
        return out;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //creating different cars
    CAuto car1("8421841", "lada", "yellow", 1999, 50000);
    //creating CAvtopark objects
    CAvtopark park1(car1, "avtopark1", "veriga1", 5, 30);
    vector<CAvtopark> parkove{ park1 }; 
    cout << parkove[0];
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the copy constructor I can get proper output. How can I still get CAuto output from a CAvtopark object without removing the copy constructor?

Comment: You have forgotten to copy `car` in your `CAvtopark` copy constructor.  You are also violating the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: Yeah, what a stupid little mistake. But even so why is it messing up the output when the copy constructor isn't even used? Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: The `CAvtopark` copy constructor is used when constructing the vector.  So `parkove[0]` has one element with an empty `CAuto` subobject (the string members will be default constructed empty strings, the integer variables are uninitialized).

Comment: It's worth noting, by the way, that you don't need to implement any copy constructors or assignment operators for your classes as coded in your post. When all the member variables of an object are either STL objects or primitive types, the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) applies.